# Azure Dedicated Cache Role not working in the cloud

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-caching

I'm sorry there's not a lot to go on with this, but some pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have an Azure Cloud Service with a web role and a dedicated cache worker role. In the web role, I'm using the cache like so in a Web Api controller:

```
var cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
_cache = cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();
```

And in the web.config:

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
    <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyProject.Workers.MyCache" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

It works fine locally using the Azure emulators, but on deploying to Azure, the controller method times out (after about 15 minutes!). The only error message I have is:

ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server: net.tcp://MyProject.Workers.MyCache:24233.

EDIT:

Similar lack of success trying to use the web role itself for caching:

```
<dataCacheClient name="default">
  <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="MyProject.WebRole" />
  <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="NotificationBased" objectCount="100000" ttlValue="300" />
  <clientNotification pollInterval="60" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

Simply nothing coming back from the server. It doesn't even time out!